# Fetch data from web api in flutter

Tags: api, flutter

I'm new to Flutter, and I want to insert the data retrieved by an API into string variables for use in another function.
Thanks for your help

my code is :------------

```
import 'dart:convert' as convert;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main(){

  var infos;
  getData() async{
    String myUrl="https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e1219328d761771cc8b9394";
    var req = await http.get(myUrl);
    infos = convert.jsonDecode(req.body);
    print(infos);
    return infos;
  }

  getData();

  // I want to Fetch data here in string variables


  runApp(new MaterialApp(
    title:'Fetch Data',
    home: new Scaffold(
      appBar:  AppBar(
        title: new Text('hello'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: new Text('test'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use stateful widget to do it.

Following code may help you more.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Fetch Data',
      home: Home(),
    ),
  );
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getData().then((value) {
      setState(() {
        infos = value;
      });
    });
  }

  var infos;
  getData() async {
    String myUrl = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e1219328d761771cc8b9394";
    var req = await http.get(myUrl);
    infos = json.decode(req.body);
    print(infos['name']);
    return infos['name'];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('hello'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: new Center(
        child: infos == null ? new Text('test') : Text(infos),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, i already realized that, but what i want in my question to retrieve for example the content of the info variable in a string variable on outside of the build widget (BuildContext context)

Comment: Accept my answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This would work perfectly, check it out:

```
class Person {
  final String name;
  final String education;
  final String skill;

  Person({this.name, this.education, this.skill});

  factory Person.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Person(
      name: json['name'],
      education: json['education'],
      skill: json['skill'],
    );
  }
}

class Fetch extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FetchState createState() => _FetchState();
}

class _FetchState extends State<Fetch> {
  Future<Person> fetchPerson;

  Future<Person> getData() async {
    String myUrl = "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e1219328d761771cc8b9394";
    var response = await http.get(myUrl);
    Map<String, dynamic> responseJson = convert.jsonDecode(response.body);
    return Person.fromJson(responseJson);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchPerson = getData();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: new Text('hello'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: fetchPerson,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text(
                    'Name is: ${snapshot.data.name}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Education is: ${snapshot.data.education}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Skill is: ${snapshot.data.skill}',
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            Text(
              snapshot.error.toString(),
            );
          }
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Output: 
[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, i already realized that, what i want in my question to retrieve for example the content of the info variable in a string variable on outside of the build widget (BuildContext context)

Comment: Dont forget to upvote and accept my answer if it helps you !

Answer (score 0):

**Fetch From API**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/semantics.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(home: Homepage()));

class Homepage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Homepagestate createState() => _Homepagestate();
}

class _Homepagestate extends State<Homepage> {
  String Stringrespon;
  List Listresponse;
  Map Mapresponse;
  List Listfacts;

  Future fetchData() async {
    http.Response response;
    response = await http
        .get('http://example.com');
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        Mapresponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        Listfacts = Mapresponse['Data'];
      });
    }
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    fetchData();
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Fetch data'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
      ),
      body: Mapresponse == null
          ? Container()
          : SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  // Text(
                  //   Mapresponse['category'].toString(),
                  //   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
                  // ),
                  ListView.builder(
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Column(
                          children: <Widget>[
                            //Image.network(Listfacts[index]['image_url']),
                            Text(
                              Listfacts[index]['LeaveTypeName'].toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                            Text(
                              Listfacts[index]['CreatedDate'].toString(),
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    itemCount: Listfacts == null ? 0 : Listfacts.length,
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Upload to Api**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'SignUp.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  final String username;
  Home({
    Key key,
    @required this.username,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _Login createState() => _Login();
}

class _Login extends State<Home> {
  Future upData(String reqDate, String fromdate, String todate,
      String description, int fdays, int hdays, int typeleave) async {
    var body = json.encode({
      "EmployeeId": 19,
      "LeaveTypeId": typeleave,
      "RequestDate": reqDate,
      "NoofFullDay": fdays,
      "NoofHalfDay": hdays,
      "Datefrom": fromdate,
      "Dateto": todate,
      "Description": description,
      "Status": 1,
      "CreatedBy": 20,
      "UpdatedBy": null,
      "CreatedDate": reqDate,
      "UpdatedDate": null,
      "IsDelete": false,
      "IsActive": true,
    });
    http.Response response;

   
    response = await http.post(
        "http://example.com/save",
        body: body,
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});
  }
  //call updata

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Smple Login",
      home: Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
        body: Center(
          child: Container(
            child: RaisedButton(onPressed: () {
              upData(
                reqDateController.text,
                fromdateController.text,
                todateController.text,
                descriptionController.text,
                int.parse(fdaysController.text),
                int.parse(hdaysController.text),
                int.parse(_myState),
              );
            }),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Fetch With Parameter**

```
 Future fetchData() async {
    var body =
        json.encode({"IsActive": true, "IsDelete": false, "CompanyId": 18});
    http.Response response;
    response = await http.post("http://example.com",
        body: body, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      setState(() {
        mapresponse = jsonDecode(response.body);
        listfacts = mapresponse['Data'];
      });
    }
  }
```

//Access
listfacts[index]['Data']),

Answer (score 0):

```
class LoginModel {
  String mobile;
  int cacheEmpId;
  int cacheCompId;
  String loginOTP;
  String oTPExpiredTime;
  String role;

  LoginModel({
    this.mobile,
    this.cacheEmpId,
    this.cacheCompId,
    this.loginOTP,
    this.oTPExpiredTime,
    this.role
  });

  LoginModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    mobile = json['Mobile'] ?? "";
    cacheEmpId=json['EmployeeId']??"";
    cacheCompId=json['CompanyId']??"";
    loginOTP = json['LoginOTP'] ?? "";
    oTPExpiredTime = json['OTPExpiredTime'] ?? "";
    role=json['ODRole']??"";
  }
}

// here is the model

import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:officediaryapp/Models/LoginModel.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:officediaryapp/Utils/Api_Utils.dart';

class LoginService {
  bool error = false;
  bool loading = true;
  var login;
  bool loginDetailserror = false;
  bool logindtailsloading = true;

  Future<LoginModel> getLogin(dynamic input, String mob) async {
    try {
      loginDetailserror = false;

      http.Response response = await http.get(ApiUtils.loginApi + mob,
          headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});

      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data["Status"] == true) {
        login = data["Data"];

        logindtailsloading = true;
        return LoginModel.fromJson(data["Data"]);
      } else {
        throw data;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      logindtailsloading = false;
      loginDetailserror = true;
    }
  }
}
 //here is getapi code
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:officediaryapp/Models/NoticeModel.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:officediaryapp/Utils/Api_Utils.dart';

class NoticeService {
  bool error = false;
  bool loading = true;
  var notice;
  bool noticeDetailserror = false;
  bool noticeetailsloading = true;

  Future<void> getNotice(dynamic input) async {
    try {
      noticeDetailserror = false;

      http.Response response = await http.post(ApiUtils.noticeApi,
          body: input, headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'});

      Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
      if (data["Status"] == true) {
        notice = data["Data"];
        notice = notice.map((_data) {
          return new NoticeModel.fromJson(_data);
        }).toList();
        print(notice);
        noticeetailsloading = false;
      } else {
        throw data;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      noticeetailsloading = false;
      noticeDetailserror = true;
    }
  }
}
//here is post API code
```